# Is Asynchronous programming in ASP without the use of AJAX? Or are they completely different things?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asynchronous, asynchronous-postback

I have been looking into ASP recently for the purpose of developing a web application.

I have read that there are ways of processing asynchronously.

As noted through this link: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheMagicOfUsingAsynchronousMethodsInASPNET45PlusAnImportantGotcha.aspx

Also the way to do it through here:
http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/aspnet-45/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-45

Does this mean processing asynchronously through the server side only or to the client as well, like when using AJAX, but without the use of JavaScript?

Basically, is this exclusive to asynchronous processing or does it mean asynchronous PostBack?

I hope you understand what I'm trying to ask.

Comment: JavaScript is required for Asynchronous.

Comment: if they are talking about asynchronous proccessing on the server, they mean that you can do more than one thing at once at the server side. then it has nothing to do with ajax, just parallelization. When talking about AJAX, there is always javascript needed.

Comment: So there is no way to communicate asynchronously to the server without the use of AJAX?

Comment: Without refreshing the page, it is only possible to communicate with the server using AJAX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said by @AlGallaf, JavaScript is required for Asynchronous. Asynchronous programming in ASP is not the same as AJAX, after researching again.